# Почему в цикле arr.reverse() работает не последовательно?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой пример:

```js
let arr_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  arr_2;

arr_2 = arr_1.reverse();
console.log("arr_2", arr_2);
```

И тут все верно работает.

А вот во втором примере нет:

```js
let arr_1 = [],
  arr_2;
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(s, i) {
  arr_1.push(arguments[1])
  arr_2 = arr_1.reverse();
})
console.log("arr_2", arr_2);
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

в `JavaScript` же код работает последовательно, с чего ж такая ерунда происходит и как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что, эта строка, каждый раз переворачивает массив.
  `arr_2 = arr_1.reverse();`
Чтобы проверить, поместите вот это в тело цикла
 `console.log("arr_2", arr_2);`
Ну или можно вот так глянуть:

```js
let arr_1 = [],
  arr_2;
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(s, i) {
  arr_1.push(arguments[1])
  console.log("arr_2_before", arr_2);
  arr_2 = arr_1.reverse();
  console.log("arr_2_after", arr_2);
})
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Чтобы исправить, уберите ревёрс из цикла.